# How do I properly create a Data Transform

Tags: pega

I'm working in a Pega 7.2 application and I want to properly create a Data Transform and trigger it from a dropdown, this dropdown has 6 items. When choosing item 1 or 3, the Data Transform should limit a text property to have a max char length of 10 (this property now has a max length of 255). I created the other elements in UI, but now I'm stucked. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have knowledge on `Validation` Rules?
If yes then I can give a simple idea.

Create a action on change of the text property.

Apply `Refresh Section` and call one `Activity`.

In the `Activity` call one `Obj-Validate` rule. In the `Security` tab of the activity choose `Validate` from the activity type dropdown.

In the `Obj-Validate` rule check the condition if Drop down property value is 1 Or 3 and text property value length is greater than 10. Then, set message on the property as the length should be 10 only.

Note :- Add Post action on change of the drop drown before applying above logic.

Another logic -

If this `Section` is getting called from a `Flowaction` rule then open the `Flowaction`, go to `Validate` tab and call the `Obj-Validate` rule which you are going to create in first logic.